# Applescript : How to write the command 'do shell script "echo | iconv"'correctly?

Tags: applescript

I'm tring to execute shell command 'iconv' in applescript,like this:

```
do shell script "echo -ne '\\x00\\x20' | iconv -f utf-16be"
```

but it returned with an error:

```
error "\riconv: (stdin):1:4: incomplete character or shift sequence"
```

How to execute the command correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
set a to "\\x00\\x20"
do shell script "/bin/echo -n " & quoted form of a & " | iconv -f utf-16be "
```

Comment: "-ne" is necessary, it's enable interpretation of backslash.

Comment: the output is same as `echo -ne '\\x00\\x20' | iconv -f utf-16be`. what's the original shell cmd ?

Comment: just more 'utf-16be' string in quoted form. @sel-fish

Comment: and the command executed successfully in terminal, and executed successfully with 'tell app "Terminal" to do script'.@sel-fish

Comment: @NFDream sorry, still can't figure out what's your original shell cmd, can you just paste that in the question? or you have solved it already ?

Comment: exactly the same , just more '\\x..\\x..', the string is a variable，each time is different.like this: `do shell script "echo -ne " & quoted form of str & " | iconv -f utf-16be "`@sel-fish